# Seeking hint for If $f_n>0$ Integrable and $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e. Then $\lim \mu(f_n)$ exists

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

The question is Let $f_n \ge 0$ Be integrable and $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mu(f_n)$ exists

My Proof: Firsly, we know that $f_n\rightarrow f$ And $f_n$ Is measurable , so is $f$. Then, $\inf_{m\ge n}f_m \le f_k$ for some $k\ge n$. Similarly, $\sup_{m\ge n}f_m \ge f_k$. Then, we know that 
$$\mu(\inf_{m\ge n}f_m)\le \mu ( f_k) \le \mu(\sup_{m\ge n}f_m)$$
Further, we know that $\lim_n \inf_{m\ge n} f_m \ge \inf_{m\ge n}f_m$, hence by monotone convergence theorem, we must have $\lim_n \mu(\inf f_n) = \mu(\lim \inf f_n)$. Similarly, we have $\lim_n \mu(\sup f_n) = \mu(\lim\sup f_n)$. But then, since $f_n \rightarrow f$, $\mu(\lim \inf f_n) = \mu (f) = \mu(\lim \sup f_n)$. Then, finally we have 
 $$ \mu(f)=\mu(\inf_{m\ge n}f_m)\le \lim \mu ( f_k) \le \lim\mu(\sup_{m\ge n}f_m) = \mu(f)$$

Hence, $\lim \mu(f_n)$ exists

I think my proof is wrong, but I am not sure where...

Comment: What exactly is $\mu(f_n)$?

Comment: @mechanodroid It is quite obvious from reading the question that it is the integral of $f_n$ with respect to the measure $\mu$.

Comment: @uniquesolution It is not obvious at all and violates almost any customary notation in this setting.

Comment: I agree with @zhw on this one. I've never seen $\mu(f)$ as a stand-in for $\int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu$. Even though I could certainly make a very good educated guess as to what $\mu(f)$ would refer to, there are ample notational choices that are more standard, any of which would be appropriate for asking a question here.

Comment: I have seen this notation in several papers and books, e.g. in Kallenberg's book. However, I would agree that this is not completely standard notation and it might have been helpful to explain it in the post.

Comment: I had no trouble at all in understanding that $\mu(f)$ means the integral of $f$ with respect to $\mu$.  To me it is a customary notation not needing explanation, or at least not in the context of integration theory.

Comment: Either there's some missing assumption, or the statement is wrong.  For example, let $f_n := \chi_{[n, n + \sin^2 n]}$ and $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: Sorry, I thought $\mu(f)$ is standard notation, and I meant integral of $f$ with respect to measure $\mu$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that $\mu(f) := \int f d\mu$. If that is what you mean, then I guess the problem would be in the phrase "Similarly, we have $\lim_n \mu(\sup f_n) = \mu(\lim\sup f_n)$". For example take the functions $f_n : [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
f_n(x) = n &\text{if } x<\frac{1}{n}\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
For this functions we have $\mu(\sup_{m\geq n} f_m)\geq \mu(f_n) = 1$ and $\lim \sup f_n = 0$ so  it is not true that  $1\leq\lim_n \mu(\sup f_n) = \mu(\lim\sup f_n)=0$. Be careful that the sequence $\sup f_n$ is decreasing so I guess you'll have to replace the hypothesis that the sequence is positive in the monotone convergence theorem by "the sequence is bounded from above".

Moreover, what you claim in the title is false as far as I see. A counterexample can be made by taking the same sequence that I gave but instead of $f_n = n$ you should put a value for each $n$ that makes the integral take alternating values for each $n$. For example $n$ if $n$ is even and $2n$ if $n$ is odd. Hope this last part can be understood.